# What is the name of the condition where you remember something while doing it together with others, but forget when you do it alone?

Tags: terminology

I want to know the name (if there is one) of the condition where you remember things while you do it on a repeated basis with a whole group of people, but forget when you are doing it alone, as if you have never done it before?

When I searched the question on similar terms on Google, I found these results.

> **Alzheimer's disease** - The most common early symptom is difficulty in remembering recent events. As the disease advances, symptoms can include problems with language, disorientation (including easily getting lost), mood swings, loss of motivation, not managing self-care, and behavioural issues.

> **Dementia** - Dementia is a broad category of brain diseases that cause a long-term and often gradual decrease in the ability to think and remember that is severe enough to affect daily functioning. Other common symptoms include emotional problems, difficulties with language, and a decrease in motivation. Consciousness is usually not affected. A diagnosis of dementia requires a change from a person's usual mental functioning and a greater decline than one would expect due to aging.

> **Hyperthymesia** - It is a condition that leads people to be able to remember an abnormally large number of their life experiences in vivid detail.

> **Athazagoraphobia** - Athazagoraphobia is a fear of forgetting someone or something, as well as a fear of being forgotten. For example, you or someone close to you may have anxiety or fear of developing Alzheimer’s disease or memory loss. This might come from caring for someone with Alzheimer’s disease or dementia.

I did not read these articles in very detail. However I already knew two of the conditions, namely, Alzheimer and Dementia. But it doesn't seem like my problem concerns these diseases or medical conditions.

*What makes me ask this?* - I faced this problem in my childhood when I used to recite the poem with my group, by-heart and fluently if I must add. However while practising it alone, it sometimes appeared like I was not able to do it, though doing it almost fifty times before time. And might I add, this happened only in the case when I performed with group and practised alone later. It didn't occur anytime when I studied the notes by myself and appear for a test or something (I mean I sometimes forget the exact lines in my notes and make something up, but this certainly is something different).

Also, I am not a doctor, nor am I pursuing career in medical science. You can say I am a medical enthusiast who likes to know about things that happens to me/ happened to me at some stage in life. Again, I am not asking about any medical advice, I just want to know if this condition has a name.

Thank you in advance to those who answer or comment on my question.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you so much. I have edited my question now. Does that help or do I need to provide more information?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.